# why viewPage keeps previous viewpage content after clicking back button

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem when I click back button while using `ViewPage`. When I enter to `ViewPage` after going out and coming back, it shows me the content of previous `ViewPage`, not new ones.

I'm entering to `ViewPage` from a `RecyclerView` and I want to change `ViewPage` content by clicking on items of `RecyclerView`.

So my problem is that why `ViewPage` is not reset to new content?

Answer (score 0):

If by saying ViewPage you mean 'ViewPager'. Then you must be displaying the content using a fragment. So when you open the ViewPager screen 'Replace' the fragment with new content.

Use this syntax:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, new Frag_four()).commit();
```

Or this one

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, new Frag_four()).commit();
```

You are facing this issue because may be you are not removing previous content from the container. So just give it a try.

**EDIT:**

In your fragment displaying activity place the following code in '`OnDestory`' method.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_container)).commit();
```

This will empty the container. So next time it will load the new fragment.

Comment: I'm exactly doing this to replace fragments. But I have the problem still!

Answer (score 0):

before committing the fragment do this! it won't remember the last open fragment and please read about `BackStack` management in fragments [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

```
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```